# How to add Constraints programmatically to default imageView and textLabel of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am currently creating my cell like this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];
  cell.imageView.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  cell.textLabel.text = @"Push me";
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  return cell;
```

Everything is working fine but some of my text which is long gets truncated at the end. How can i avoid that?? I don't want to set the numberOfLines property.

Is there a way i can arrange my imageView and textlabel a bit via constraints so that my text looks fine. I tried adding constraints to contentView of cell but that make my cell all weird.

I am new to iOS development and learning. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set `numberOfLines`. `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property will set your content bound to width without truncating it. but it will decrease font size if required.

```
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Thanks!! But is there a way i can add constraints to it programmatically between it's imageView and textLabel.

Comment: Yes you can add constraints. Please check how to add constraints programmatically in stackoverflow. You will have lots of results to go through. If not found satisfactory, let me know here in comment. I will give you a code here by updating my answer.

Comment: I tried. but me cell now is all looking weird... i translatesAutoResizingMask to NO for imageView and textLabel, then added visual constraints to cell.contentView like with string as H:|-[imageView]-[textLabel]-| but it's not working... i tried to add constants in between as well but still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add constraint programmatically, 
Step 1 - Drag and drop the cell on UITableview
Step 2 - Design your cell with image view and label , use constraints 
Step 3 - Create CustomCell.h and CustomCell.m file which will be inherited from UITableViewCell
Step 4 - create IBOutlet for image view and label in CustomCell.h
Step 5 - In your ViewController -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
   cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataAraay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView *imgarrow=[[UIImageView alloc]init ];

imgarrow.frame=CGRectMake(230,2, 27, 27);

imgarrow.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_mark@2x.png"];

[cell addSubview:imgarrow];

//write same code for UILabel

//change rectmake values

Comment: i am using the default imageView provided by the cell

Comment: than autoresizingmask